# Does Allah create a new soul every time a couple..has it?

Tags: allah, sex, soul

Asalamalikum So I asked the question to a learned muslim as his answer was “I don’t know” so here I came

Comment: No. Allah has already created all the souls. He doesn't create new ones.

Comment: This question isn't answerable -as we don't know what Allah does or leaves that's beyond our knowledge. Any answer would be rather an assumption unless Allah gave us any hints by a kind of revelation. However I tend to say no because the soul according hadith is added after fertilization.

Comment: What does the question ask in the first place? Are you asking whether God creates a new soul whenever a couple have sex?

Comment: According to the tafsir of the verse 7:172 all the souls already existed before they came into this world. And the Hadith mentioned in the answer below also supports it, thus we understand that souls have already been created. Believing that souls already exist does not go against the verse 17:85, with the little knowledge that Allah azzawajjal has given us we affirm the verses in Quran and Sunnah.

Answer (score 1):

Prophet (SAWW) said: “Souls are like crowds which gather together. The ones who met before get on well. The ones, who did not meet before, cannot get on very well and separate.” (*Bukhari, Anbiya, 2; Muslim, Birr, 159; Abu Dawud, Adab, 19*).

This hadith states that people met somewhere before they came to world. Clearly, as it cannot have happened in mothers’ wombs, it means they indeed existed before and were created before they came into mothers’ wombs. Hence meaning, Allah doesn't create a new soul everytime.